# Is there still a repository for debian etch packages?

Tags: repository

I know etch is unsupported now but i still have etch machines that i can not upgrade right now.

So my question aims for a repo to put into my sources.list.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All Debian releases are archived at [`archive.debian.org`](http://archive.debian.org), so

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ etch main non-free contrib
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ etch/updates main non-free contrib
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-volatile/ etch/volatile main non-free contrib

deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ etch main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ etch/updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian-volatile/ etch/volatile main non-free contrib
```

(And if you need a package that never went into a stable release, go to [`snapshot.debian.org`](http://snapshot.debian.org).)

Comment: could you please post the deb-src entries also? please

Comment: @siju Entries for source packages are exactly like entries with binary packages, only with `deb-src` instead of `deb`.